# Как получить значение переменной из пользовательской программы для модуля ядра?

Tags: linux, kernel

Есть программа написанная в user-mode. 
К примеру она содержит массив чисел.

Как можно прочитать и записать этот массив в модуле ядра, при условии, что считывать этот массив надо будет периодично?

Comment: http://wiki.tldp.org/kernel_user_space_howto

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-kernel-memory-access/

Comment: Это вам придётся угадать, по какому адресу этот самый массив находится. (Если целевая программа сотрудничает, то адрес лучше спросить у неё.)

Comment: а что значит сотрудничает? @VladD

Comment: Ну, если её можно попросить каким-то образом выдать наружу нужный адрес. К примеру: программа при запуске с определённым ключом командной строки пишет этот самый адрес в файл.

Comment: Я тоже об этом думал, пользовательская программа будет записывать адрес массива в файл, а модуль ядра будет считывать из файла адрес и значение массива.. хммм, я думал можно как-то программно вытащить значение.

Comment: Вы изначально неверно ставите вопрос. В системе master-slave отношений ядро — slave. Так что ваша программа из user-space может регулярно передавать в ядро любыми доступными ABI (sysfs, netlink, /dev (ioctl), …